# How to do elements wise addition or multiplication R with 4 X 3 and 3 X 5 vector in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do element wise multiplication of two matrix a and b I'm getting the error saying

> Error in a + b : non-conformable arrays

```
data <- matrix(151:162, nrow=4)
data2 <- matrix(221:235, nrow=3)
```

> Error in a * b : non-conformable arrays

However when I'm doing actual matrix multiplication I'm getting the desired output. Can anyone suggest me how to fix that.

Comment: HINT: does 4*3 equal 3*5?

Comment: are you trying to say it's not possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

150:162 are 13 elements and 220:235 are 16. `length(150:162)` will show. These aren't 4x3 or 3x5 matrices.

Update: For elementwise operation the dimensions of the matrices need to be identical. See `size(data)`. So these operations are not possible with 3x4 and 4x3.

Comment: number of elements are different.

Comment: Addition is performed entrywise. So number of rows and columns need to match. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition).
If you want to multiply elementwise with ```data*data2``` it need to be the same. 
But matrix multiplication is performed with ```data%*%data2```. As you mentioned, this works and results in a 4x5 matrix.

Comment: yes, #Speaka for actual matrix multiplication the only col of the left matrix must be equal to the row of the right matrix. but in the case of element-wise I think no of elements or dimension must be the same in both matrix.. isn't it?

Comment: ```data <- matrix(151:162, nrow=4)
 data2 <- matrix(221:232, nrow=3)
data*data2``` doesn't work either. If the count of all elements match you can do `as.vector(data)*as.vector(data2)`. Hower it's propably not what you want.

Comment: No speaka  i dont want this. By the way thanks..